# How to prove this lemma about eta expansion?

Tags: variadic-functions, coq

([here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/33cecff989800e295226b9301bd2e19a) is a gist of my work so far.)

Coq comes with a rule about eta reduction, allowing us to prove something like the following:

```
Variables X Y Z : Type.
Variable f : X -> Y -> Z.

Lemma eta1 : (fun x => f x) = f.
Proof.
  auto.
Qed.
```

The eta rule is not merely an equality rewrite, so we can use it beneath binders as well:

```
Lemma eta2 : (fun x y => f x y) = f.
Proof.
  auto.
Qed.
```

Of course, one would expect that you could generalize this to an `f` of arbitrary arity.  Here is my naïve attempt:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Fixpoint toType(ts : list Type)(t : Type) : Type :=
  match ts with
  |[]    => t
  |u::vs => u -> (toType vs t)
  end.

Compute toType [X;Y] Z.

(*
     = X -> Y -> Z
     : Type
*)

Fixpoint etaexpand(ts : list Type) : forall t : Type, toType ts t -> toType ts t :=
  match ts as ts return forall t, toType ts t -> toType ts t with
  |[]    => fun t x => x
  |u::vs => fun t f (x:u) => etaexpand vs t (f x)
  end.

Compute etaexpand [X;Y] Z f.
(*
     = fun (x : X) (x0 : Y) => f x x0
     : toType [X; Y] Z
*)

Lemma etaexpand_id : forall ts t f, etaexpand ts t f = f.
Proof.
  induction ts; intros.
  auto.
  simpl.
  (*stuck here*)
```

I get stuck on the inductive step of the above lemma.  Naturally, I want to rewrite using the inductive hypothesis, but I cannot since the relevant subterm occurs beneath a binder.  Of course, I myself know that the inductive hypothesis *should* be usable beneath binders, since it's just a chain of eta rewrites.  I'm wondering then if there's a clever way to state and convince Coq of this fact.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone's curious, [here's](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/75634513cbe66ed38eb15091994146c2) the solution I came up with after some thought.

The key is to simultaneously prove the following "niceness" property for `etaexpand ts t`:

```
Definition nice{X Y}(F : Y -> Y) := (forall y, F y = y) -> forall f : X -> Y, 
  (fun x => F (f x)) = f.
```